# WKScriptMessageHandler userContentController didReceive message does not get called

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, wkwebview

Why does `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` not get called for deleteAccount event(or any other event)?

Here is the code

React

```
const handleDelete = () => {
        if (window?.android) {
            window?.android?.clickedOnDeleteAccountBtn();
        } else {
            window?.webkit?.messageHandlers?.deleteAccount?.postMessage();
        };
    };
```

iOS

```
struct ContentWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let frame: CGRect
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "deleteAccount?")
        contentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "deleteAccount")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        if let requestUrl = URL(string: "https://blabla.web.app?platform=ios") {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: requestUrl))
        }

        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    // MARK: Coordinator

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

        @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

        private var parent: ContentWebView
        private var webViewNavigationSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil

        init(_ webView: ContentWebView) {
            self.parent = webView
        }

        deinit {
            webViewNavigationSubscriber?.cancel()
        }

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            print(message.body)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same issue, for me the problem came from react side. Apparently there needs to be something inside `.postMessage`

So the very easy fix was to change it to

```
window?.webkit?.messageHandlers?.deleteAccount?.postMessage('deleteAccount');
```